# Could not get endpoint for worker (jk_handler::mod_jk.c)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, tomcat, mod-jk

I am using Apache2 with Tomcat on debian Lenny, When I try to access the site, its working but sometime I am getting error 500 "Internal server error".

From the mod_jk.log, I could find the following errors

[Mon Oct 29 16:46:00 2012] [30901:139706010294016] [warn] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3117): Unable to get the free endpoint for worker worker1 from 1 slots
[Mon Oct 29 16:46:00 2012] [30901:139706010294016] [error] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2552): Could not get endpoint for worker=worker1

The following are the configurations in my workers.properties

worker.worker1.type=ajp13

worker.worker1.host=localhost

worker.worker1.port=8009

worker.worker1.cachesize=10

worker.worker1.cache_timeout=600

worker.worker1.socket_keepalive=1

worker.worker1.reclycle_timeout=300

Can someone help me with finding and fixing the issue?